# Optimize UI layers in a listview (+screenshots)

Tags: performance, android-listview, android, android-custom-view

I'm analyzing my approach with Gmail's android developer's team approach in order to *optimize* drawing times and generally create more efficient apps.

### My approach:

Below is the hierarchy inside a listview. It's quite straightforward. ExpandableListContentItem extends a Relative layout which has 3 Views:

[image]

### Gmail app:

The following screenshot is how the listview in Gmail app works (SwipableListView). It's interesting to see that there is only one View (I guess `aY` extends ConvertationItemView) which in reality is quite more complicated than mine (I see 3 texts, 1 photo, 1 icon/button).

[image]

### Question:

I would assume that this is a more lightweight approach to get rendered, is it so? Even if it takes me more time to code an optimal single customview per listview item it is worth the performance that it offers?

Finally the only way I know so far is to inflate an existing view inside another which is basically the first approach. I guess now my challenge would be to combine that relativeLayout with the 3 nested views into one. Is that correct?

PS:examples, open source code are welcome.

Comment: It shortens traversals of the view hierarchy during measure, layout, and draw passes. The amount of stuff being drawn may or may not be reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I would assume that this is a more lightweight approach to get rendered, is it so?`

Yes it is. When you consider hierarchy, every parent measures their dimensions and passes it to child views from top to bottom. Reducing layers and having more flat view will save time.

`Even if it takes me more time to code an optimal single customview per listview item it is worth the performance that it offers?`

Depends on application you are developing. Depends on number of items in a list and how you get them. When you scroll through the list, if you think it is slow you might want to try that approach. I tried it on my previous applications and I could see the difference.

`I guess now my challenge would be to combine that relativeLayout with the 3 nested views into one.`

I don't know what you mean by combining them but the way Gmail does it that they have their Custom View. You can create your custom view.

Besides that, another thing to consider is **overdraw**. It is as important as having flat views. If you activate **GPU Overdraw** from developer tools and look at Gmail app row, you will see 0 overdraw. Make sure your code has no overdraw.

For further reading I would recommend you to check these blogs :

[Performance Tuning On Android](http://blog.venmo.com/hf2t3h4x98p5e13z82pl8j66ngcmry/performance-tuning-on-android)

[Android Performance Case Study](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/)

Comment: no Gmail app is having overdraw issue

Comment: see gmail app:  https://ibb.co/3ptYspB